# How to unmarshal from CSV to Bean with Apache Camel and Bindy?

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel

I'm trying to write my first code with [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) right now. I try to follow the examples from [Camel in Action](http://www.manning.com/ibsen/), but I want to use my own example data.

## What I want to do

Right now I want to read from a CSV file and get each line as a java bean.

Here is my junit test:

```
@Test
public void testCsvWithBindy() throws Exception {
    MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:queue.csv");
    mock.expectedMessageCount(2);

    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();

    CsvBean line1 = mock.getReceivedExchanges().get(0).getIn()
            .getBody(CsvBean.class);
    assertEquals("row 01", line1.getFirst());
}

public RouteBuilder createRoute() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            context.setTracing(true);

            from("file://src/test/resources?noop=true&fileName=test.csv")
                .unmarshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv, "my.package.for.csvrecord")
                .to("mock:queue.csv");
        }
    };
}
```

The CSV contains this:

```
row 01,row 02,,row 04
row 11, row 12, row 13, row 14
```

And this is my CsvRecord:

```
@CsvRecord(separator = ",")
public class CsvBean {
@DataField(pos = 1)
private String first;
@DataField(pos = 2)
private String second;
@DataField(pos = 3)
private String third;
@DataField(pos = 4)
private String fourth;

public String getFirst() {
    return first;
}

public void setFirst(String first) {
    this.first = first;
}

public String getSecond() {
    return second;
}

public void setSecond(String second) {
    this.second = second;
}

public String getThird() {
    return third;
}

public void setThird(String third) {
    this.third = third;
}

public String getFourth() {
    return fourth;
}

public void setFourth(String fourth) {
    this.fourth = fourth;
}
}
```

## My Problem

When I run this test, the context is started and the route is loaded. But nothing is coming through. After about 10s the context is automatically stopped and my test fails. This is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: mock://queue.csv Received message count. Expected: <2> but was: <0>
at org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint.fail(MockEndpoint.java:1086)
at org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint.assertEquals(MockEndpoint.java:1068)
at org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint.doAssertIsSatisfied(MockEndpoint.java:367)
at org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied(MockEndpoint.java:346)
at org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied(MockEndpoint.java:334)
at org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied(MockEndpoint.java:172)
at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.assertMockEndpointsSatisfied(CamelTestSupport.java:391)
at my.package.for.unittests.CsvToBeanWithBindyTest.testCsvWithBindy(CsvToBeanWithBindyTest.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
```

## Need help with

I guess I'm missing something obvious, maybe something that has to do with the test setup and not so much with my CsvRecord or my route. Can you give me a tip or maybe an URL to a better tutorial? The book is not very helpful at this point... :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again, right after posting my question, I found the answer myself. ;-) Here is a working junit test:

```
public class CsvToBeanWithBindyTest extends CamelTestSupport {
@Test
public void testCsv() throws Exception {
    MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:queue.csv");
    mock.expectedMessageCount(1);

    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();

    List line1 = (List) mock.getReceivedExchanges().get(0).getIn()
            .getBody();
    Map map1 = (Map) line1.get(0);
    CsvBean csv1 = (CsvBean) map1.get("my.package.CsvBean");
    assertEquals("row 01", csv1.getFirst());

    Map map2 = (Map) line1.get(1);
    CsvBean csv2 = (CsvBean) map2.get("my.package.CsvBean");
    assertEquals("row 11", csv2.getFirst());
}

@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            context.setTracing(true);

            from("file://src/test/resources?noop=true&fileName=test.csv")
                .unmarshal(new BindyCsvDataFormat("my.package"))
                .to("mock:queue.csv");
        }
    };
}
}
```

The unexpected thing for me is that I get a `List` from my endpoint route which in turn holds many `Map`s. Each map has a key `my.package.MyBeanClass` with the value set to the actual unmarshalled row from my CSV file.

Comment: Did you ever work around the Map issue? I'm the map as well, where I have to extract out the bean, rather than an ArrayList of the beans? This page (http://camel.apache.org/bindy.html) makes reference to the map, but doesn't give a good enough explanation of why it is there?

Comment: Sorry, no updates from me on the map. I accepted it as the way Bindy works:

"The reason behind this is that each line can correspond to more than one object. This can be confusing when you simply expect one object to be returned per line." (from the URL)

Comment: Hi, i was also doing the same CSV to Object conversion, but i am facing illegal argument exception for int or Integer data type. Please check my question on the same-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627864/apache-camelbindy-illegal-argument-exception