# Apache camel:bindy illegal argument exception

Tags: apache-camel, rhel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I am doing data format conversion between POJO to CSV and vice versa. In this while converting CSV to Object file(Unmarshalling) i am getting illegal argument exception for int data type. Only for string its working fine.
Below is my POJO

```
@CsvRecord(separator="//|",crlf="UNIX",generateHeaderColumns=false)
public class EmployeeVO implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -663135747565879908L;

    @DataField(pos=1)
    private String name;

    @DataField(pos=3)
    private Integer age;

    @DataField(pos=2)
    private String grade;
        // getter setter
}
```

csv data

```
sumit|4th standrad|22
```

the above csv is generated from the above POJO. But at the time of converting CSV to POJO i am getting folloing exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parsing error detected for field defined at the position: 3, line: 1
```

following are my camel - context file for your reference

marshal

```
<route>
        <from uri="cxf:bean:rtoemplyeeService"/>
        <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" id="stringInput"/>
        <bean ref="govtEmpBean" method="getEmployeeCSV" beanType="govtEmpBean" id="govtEmp"/>
        <log message="before marshalling ================== ${body}"/>
        <marshal ref="bindyDataformat">
            <bindy type="Csv" packages="com.mycompany.converter.vo"/>
        </marshal>
        <log message="after marshalling ================== ${body}"/>
        <to uri="file://D:/JATO_WORK/repo_bkp/csv/"/>
        <setBody>
            <simple>CSV output is generated at file system </simple>
        </setBody>
    </route>
```

un marshal

```
 <route id="csvtoobject">
        <from uri="file://D:/JATO_WORK/repo_bkp/csv?delay=10000&amp;initialDelay=10"/>
        <log message="csv string ============= ${body}"/>
        <unmarshal ref="bindyDataformat"/>
        <log message="${body}"/>
        <bean ref="govtEmpBean" method="printCSVObject" beanType="govtEmpBean" id="govtEmp"/>
    </route>
```

Comment: is POJO the java term for a POD type?

Comment: its a plain old java object, simple java bean with property and getter setters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the csv record as follows

```
@CsvRecord(separator = "\\|")
```